# Querying nested mongo document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have few JSON documents stored in MongoDB that are basically error reports, i.e. each document contains a nested data structure mismatches between datasets. They look like the following:

```
    {
      "nodename": "BLAH"
      "errors": {
        "PC": {
          "value": {
            "PC93196": [
              "post",
              "casper"
            ],
            "PC03196": [
              "netdb"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

So in the above case, a process/tool determines the `PC` value of `PC93196` and `PC03196`. `netdb` in this case reported a different PC value to that of `post` and `casper`.

How do I query for all documents that have errors where the process/tool `casper` is involved?

Answer (score 0):

The document schema doesn't really lend itself to being queried very easily in the way you're trying to.  This is because the `value` object is composed of named objects, rather than being an Array of objects.  I.e. the `value` object has two properties: `PC93196` and `PC03196`.

If your document was structured slightly differently it would be much easier to query in the way you want.  For example a document structure like this:

```
{
  "nodename": "BLAH",
  "errors": {
    "PC": [
      {
        "name": "PC93196",
        "type": [
          "post",
          "casper"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "PC03196",
        "type": [
          "netdb"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Would allow you to write a query like this:

```
db.errors.aggregate([{$unwind:"$errors.PC"},{$match:{"errors.PC.type":"casper"}}])
```

which would provide a result:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5763c480dad14fd061657f91"), "nodename" : "BLAH", "errors" : { "PC" : { "name" : "PC93196", "type" : [ "post", "casper" ] } } }
```